# Wordpress: JavaScript plugin with bootstrap and wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I cant get the js for a lightbox plugin to work correctly. The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   bootstrap-lightbox.js?ver=4.1:113

My functions.php:

```
function bootstrap_js() {


wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .         '/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstraplightbox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-lightbox.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_js');
```

And then I have this in my header.php

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ) ?>
```

I can find out whats wrong. I have been googling for hours now and none of the fixes I have found has worked for me (or understood them might be another reason).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the line to enqueue jQuery in your header, WordPress will handle that automagically as it is listed as a dependency of bootstrapjs. Additionally, you should probably list bootstrapjs as a dependency of bootstraplightbox like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstraplightbox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-lightbox.js', array('jquery', 'bootstrapjs'), '', true );
```

This will make sure that the bootstrapjs file is loaded before bootstraplightbox, as I am assuming that must happen.